# Extract boundary points from BoundaryMeshRegion

Tags: graphics, mesh

Is there a way to extract the boundary points of a `BoundaryMeshRegion`?

For instance, let's take the test data

```
pts = Table[{x, RandomReal[{(x - 3)^2, 9}]}, {x, 0, 4, 0.001}];
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

```
ConvexHullMesh[pts, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Ideally I would even want to have only those points at the lower edge of the boundary (that is, those points that represent the function `(x - 3)^2`).

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is easy:  `MeshCoordinates@mesh` - how to only grab the lower points?  That's a bit more complicated I would think

Comment: That answers the main part of the question. For the second part, I realize that "lower edge" is not well defined and requires manual thresholding. I will accept your comment if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @JasonB.s method, would the equivalent polygon suffice?

```
pts = Table[{x,RandomReal[{(x-3)^2,9}]},{x,0,4,0.001}];
mesh = ConvexHullMesh[pts];

polygonIndices = MeshCells[mesh, 2]
polygon = GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[mesh],MeshCells[mesh,2]];
polygon //Normal
Graphics[{
    FaceForm[LightGray], EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[Large],Red]],
    polygon
 }]
```

> {Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
>      20, 21, 22, 25, 27, 29, 31, 35, 34, 33, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24, 23}]}
>
> {Polygon[{{0., 9.}, {0.033, 8.80399}, {0.05, 8.70302}, {0.155, 
>       8.09864}, {0.286, 7.37309}, {0.37, 6.92772}, {0.458, 6.46211}, {0.567, 
>       5.92525}, {0.611, 5.71406}, {0.976, 4.11626}, {1.261, 3.03759}, {1.596, 
>       1.98138}, {1.735, 1.61816}, {1.875, 1.31337}, {1.956, 1.1498}, {2.191, 
>       0.689023}, {2.272, 0.576532}, {2.777, 0.0601964}, {2.901, 
>       0.0130619}, {3.272, 0.0808712}, {3.539, 0.355987}, {3.61, 
>       0.440961}, {3.785, 0.662594}, {3.969, 1.07353}, {3.982, 1.26786}, {3.99, 
>       1.45703}, {4., 1.70252}, {3.998, 4.98624}, {3.997, 5.55114}, {3.995, 
>       6.15607}, {3.983, 8.62608}, {3.974, 8.93544}, {3.949, 8.95805}, {3.707, 
>       8.99464}, {3.645, 8.99709}}]}

[image]

Another idea is to use a property:

```
mesh["BoundaryPolygons"]
```

> {Polygon[{{0., 9.}, {0.033, 8.80399}, {0.05, 8.70302}, {0.155, 
>       8.09864}, {0.286, 7.37309}, {0.37, 6.92772}, {0.458, 
>       6.46211}, {0.567, 5.92525}, {0.611, 5.71406}, {0.976, 
>       4.11626}, {1.261, 3.03759}, {1.596, 1.98138}, {1.735, 
>       1.61816}, {1.875, 1.31337}, {1.956, 1.1498}, {2.191, 
>       0.689023}, {2.272, 0.576532}, {2.777, 0.0601964}, {2.901, 
>       0.0130619}, {3.272, 0.0808712}, {3.539, 0.355987}, {3.61, 
>       0.440961}, {3.785, 0.662594}, {3.969, 1.07353}, {3.982, 
>       1.26786}, {3.99, 1.45703}, {4., 1.70252}, {3.998, 
>       4.98624}, {3.997, 5.55114}, {3.995, 6.15607}, {3.983, 
>       8.62608}, {3.974, 8.93544}, {3.949, 8.95805}, {3.707, 
>       8.99464}, {3.645, 8.99709}}]}

Comment: Indeed, that is a nice way of sorting the edge points. The points themselves are then accessible by `First[List@@First[Normal[polygon]])]`. Thresholding (e.g., on the derivative) can be applied to select the lower edge.

Answer (score 2):

```
pts = Table[{x, RandomReal[{(x - 3)^2, 9}]}, {x, 0, 4, 0.001}];
mymesh = ConvexHullMesh[pts];
mypts = Select[MeshCoordinates[mymesh], #[[2]] < .899 &];
myboundary = Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Line[mypts]}, AspectRatio -> 1];
myplot = Plot[(x - 3)^2, {x, 0, 4},
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Blue}];
  Show[myboundary, myplot]
```

[image]

This appears a bit different from the poser's question because of the random generation of initial points.

Comment: That is already part of the question. The question was how to extract the boundary points from this object.